# Spring + Hibernate Self join case

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, nhibernate-mapping

Can someone help me on the below scenario:

I have two tables with columns:

```
1) Employee: empId, empName
2) Colleague : colleagueId, empId(as a foreign key refers Employee.empId)
```

Data might be in the tables:

```
Employee Table
empId    empName
1        Devesh
2        Nitin
3        Deep
```

Colleague Table

```
colleagueId    empId
1              1
2              2
3              1
4              2
5              3
```

So i want to build the relationsip in hibernate between these two tables. I want to use JPA to persistent my objects or retrieve.

Please help me out

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, Can some body help me on this

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is a classic and very simple unidirectional `@ManyToOne` case.  In this scenario, the `Employee` is managed with no knowledge of `Colleague`.

Your mapping would look something like the following:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "empId")
  private Long id;
  @Column(name = "empName")
  private String employeeName;
  // getter & setters 
}

@Entity
public class Colleague {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "colleagueId")
  private Long id;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "empId", referencedColumnName = "empId")
  private Employee employee;
  // getter & setters
}
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for you reply. @Naros.  One question, how will i get Colleague based on Employee.

Comment: Assuming you know your employee id, you could write a simple query like `SELECT c FROM Colleague c JOIN Employee e WHERE e.id = :id`.  Just because the relationship is unidirectional doesn't mean you can't get a list of colleagues based on a given employee attribute.